# Tkinter Entry to accept Unicode text?

Tags: unicode, tkinter, tk-toolkit, keyboard-layout

I have a Tkinter Entry widget and a [Hungarian keyboard](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Hungary.svg). When I press the <kbd>ő</kbd> button on the keyboard, the Entry widget displays `õ`. <kbd>ű</kbd> becomes `û`. (I haven't had this problem in other applications since Windows 3.1.)

**Edit:**

I do have two language settings on this computer and when I start changing them around, the problem disappears.

[image: screenshot]

What can I do to make Tkinter handle my input correctly?

Comment: What we really need to hunt this down is the log of exactly what `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` events were sent and what the `lParam` and `wParam` fields were when the problem occurred.

Comment: @DonalFellows Does Windows send *initial* `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` events to the application? Because the problem only occurred before I started changing the languages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a problem with *changes* to the keyboard layout, as Tk (the library under Tkinter) on Windows doesn't do anything with the `lParam` in the the `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` messages. That's [a bug](https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/a9bd2ab98b).

Comment: Are you sure? In my case, the keyboard layout doesn't change, only the language.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Tk ticket here:
[Tk Ticket](https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/a9bd2ab98bdedf4420f6f663efabf4448f88a614)

Unfortunately, the issue might be TkInter only.

Would it be possible to get more details and make a test using plain Tcl/Tk ?
So, download a current tcl/tk starkit or distribution and try the script:

```
pack [entry .e]
```

and look, if the problem is present there too ?

Please report to the tk ticket, anonymous login might be required there.

Comment: Yes, the issue is present there too.

Comment: I don't believe this can be a Tkinter only issue; Tkinter is a Python binding layer on top of Tcl/Tk (unlike PerlTk) and doesn't introduce any place where it would intercept or misinterpret messages in a way characteristic of this bug. If it was a binding-layer issue, _lots_ of non-ASCII characters would come out wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Can't reproduce your problem. Works for me with Tk and tkinter as well. See the Tk ticket.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: In my case the keyboard layout does not change! Also the issue is present _initially_ but disappears after changing the _language_ and can not be brought back.